# problem with xslt output

Tags: xml, xslt

In the .xml file, I have like this:

```
<function>true</function>
```

In the schema ile, I have defined it as a boolean. So now, It is working correctly. BUT for XSLT file i.e .xsl,

Comment: Can you add an example xsl describing what you want to do?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution that doesn't use any XSLT conditional instructions. Also wait for an even shorter hack, coming ... :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`xsl:choose`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_choose.asp):

```
<td>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="function = 'true'">@</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>&#32;</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</td>
```

Comment: @user507087 - sorry, it supposed to be the entity for space (`&#32;`). I missed out the #.

Comment: That space entity will be remove from the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

**This can be done very simply, not at all requiring conditional XSLT instructions**, and completely in the spirit of the XSLT (push-style):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="function/text()[.='true']">@</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="function/text()[not(.='true')]">
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="function">
  <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document**:

```
<function>true</function>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<td>@</td>
```

**When the same transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<function>false</function>
```

**again the correct, wanted result is produced**:

```
<td> </td>
```

**Finally**, using a hack (in XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0 this isn't necessary), we can use just a single template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="function">
  <td>
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(substring('@', 1 div (.='true')),
           substring(' ', 1 div not(.='true'))
          )
   "/>
   </td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think using conditionals is better than having to write the condition twice.

Comment: @svick: The alternative you think is better has much lower (probably close to zero) composabitiy. Also, it has significantly bigger complexity and is significantly more prone to committing errors.